# SIPO (Serial Input Parallel Output) FSM synthesis problem

Tags: verilog, fsm

I want to write a Serial to Parallel conversion in Verilog, and I can't realize what is wrong with my code. It doesn't synthesize, and not even the ISE shows what the problem is.  Can anyone help me?

I guess the problem is around the second always block.  The part:

```
if (STATE == TRANSMIT)
                    PAR_OUT[COUNTER] = SER_IN;
```

seems wrong to me, but I can't understand what to change or test.

```
module SIPO(
     input SER_IN,
     input RST,
     input CLK,
     input LOAD,
     output reg READY,
     output reg [7:0] PAR_OUT
    );

parameter IDLE = 2'b00, START = 2'b01, TRANSMIT = 2'b10, STOP = 2'b11;
reg [1:0] STATE;
reg [2:0] COUNTER;

always @ ( posedge CLK or negedge RST)
    if (~RST)
    begin
        STATE <= IDLE;
        READY <= 1;
        COUNTER <= 0;   
    end
    else
    begin
        if (STATE == IDLE)
        begin
            READY <= 1;
            COUNTER <= 0;
            if (LOAD)
            begin
                STATE <= START;
            end
            else
                STATE <= IDLE;
        end
        else
            if (STATE == START)
                STATE <= TRANSMIT;
            else
                if (STATE == TRANSMIT)
                    begin
                        COUNTER <= COUNTER + 1;
                        if (COUNTER == 7)
                            STATE <= STOP;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        STATE <= IDLE;
                        READY <= 1;
                    end     
    end

always @( * )
    begin
        if (STATE == IDLE)
            PAR_OUT = 1;
        else
            if (STATE == START)
                PAR_OUT = 0;
            else
                if (STATE == TRANSMIT)
                    PAR_OUT[COUNTER] = SER_IN;
                else
                    PAR_OUT = 1;        
    end 

endmodule
```

Comment: I guess it shows some error message? There is no problem with Quartus

Comment: i do not see anything wrong with the code.  What does it mean "it doesn't synthesize"?

Comment: PAR_OUT should be a registered output and therefore should never be assigned in a combinational block (ie always @(*)).  What you need to do is move all the PAR_OUT code up to the always @(posedge) block into the appropriate place.  Also, don't assign to a bit, but instead shift the serial value in (ie. `PAR_OUT <= {SER_IN, PAR_OUT[7:1]};`)Note that any combinational block needs to assign to every signal that is assigned in that block every time regardless of the flow through the if-else sequence or you will get latches which is almost never what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think your suspicion might be correct regarding `PAR_OUT[COUNTER]`.  When I [synthesize your code on edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2_RU) with Yosys, it infers latches for `PAR_OUT`, which you likely do not want.

`PAR_OUT` is 8 bits wide, but you only assign 1 of the 8 bits at a time in the `TRANSMIT` state, which means the other 7 bits retain their state.  For example, if `COUNTER`=3, then only `PAR_OUT[3]` is assigned.

I recoded your combo logic, simplifying it with a `case` statement to make the issue more evident (it *should* be functionally equivalent to your `if/else` code):

```
always @* begin
    case (STATE)
        TRANSMIT: PAR_OUT[COUNTER] = SER_IN;    // Assign to only 1 bit <---
        START   : PAR_OUT = 8'h00;              // Assign to all 8 bits
        default : PAR_OUT = 8'h01;              // Assign to all 8 bits
    endcase
end
```

---

If you can afford one cycle of latency, you could use sequential logic for `PAR_OUT`, such as a shift register.